Error "Could not move temporary workspace" when building MCreator
I tried to open up my mod and the Gradle was running properly but then it failed for some reason.
Here is the exact things that went wrong
Executing Gradle task: eclipse Build info:
   MCreator 2024.2.32117, forge-1.20.1, 64-bit, 15509 MB, Windows 11, JVM 21.0.3, JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Pylo\MCreator\jdk, started on: 2024-08-30-19:45:41 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'morefoods'.
> A build operation failed. Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\noname\.mcreator\gradle\caches\8.8\transforms\7f3f7cfc4fbe146884af051af13661ea-232c4653-db4b-46d2-9d0d-8cc61ea2626f) to immutable location (C:\Users\noname\.mcreator\gradle\caches\8.8\transforms\7f3f7cfc4fbe146884af051af13661ea)
> Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\noname\.mcreator\gradle\caches\8.8\transforms\7f3f7cfc4fbe146884af051af13661ea-232c4653-db4b-46d2-9d0d-8cc61ea2626f) to immutable location (C:\Users\noname\.mcreator\gradle\caches\8.8\transforms\7f3f7cfc4fbe146884af051af13661ea)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 9s

BUILD FAILED Task completed in 9 seconds

I already tried the help.gradle.org website and it did not show my issue

This question is similar to: React Native Error : java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
